# Why does my user name keep changing?

Tags: support, display-names

My username keeps being changed to a default username. It's the second time this happens. What might cause this?

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? What exactly happened? When did that happened? have you done anything on the site? Have you logged from another machine?

Comment: Is your question about your username, or the fact that you can't post your questions?

Comment: What does the title of this question have to do with its body?

Comment: I had to add some filler text because it wouldn't let me submit

Comment: Yeah well obviously it wouldn't let you submit because your question doesn't have any information...

Comment: So you're really asking "Why am I not automatically user1806244 on all sites?" ....

Comment: No my user name was xpedobearx and it keeps changing to user180.. idk why

Comment: @user1806244 Perhaps you should have actually read the error message and considered what it was saying, rather than just copied it to try to make it go away.

Comment: @user1806244 Maybe because that username isn't allowed? Nice trolling.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Could you care to elaborate?

Comment: `Offensive Username + Question Blocked == Royally F**ked.`

Comment: geez it's just a stupid user name who would be offended by it and why

Comment: You really need an explanation for that one?

Comment: @user1806244 You're right, it is a stupid username, why would you want it?

Comment: yes bc i dont get it. r u offended by the word "pedo" or what? does "killer21" offend u too? i think u need to relax and don't take everything seriously

Comment: It's unprofessional at the very least. I'm not particularly easily offended, but I do think we should at least attempt to have a certain level of professionalism on the site. And your username certainly does not meet that requirement. You can tattoo it on your forehead for all I care, but let's keep the site clean.

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/500x/9869953.jpg

Answer (score 16):

Given that your stated username was related to a bear with a particular affinity for people too young to be Stack Exchange members, I go out on a limb and say "Because people found it offensive".

Approach the network in a professional manner please. You can give yourself a lot of names, but some are just a no go.

Comment: Yup. And to add to this; a moderator changed the name back to the default. Oh, and this only happened once, so the "keep changing" in the question here seems to be slightly... incorrect.

Comment: I guess it's twice, now ;)

Comment: Let's just say that I won't try to explain the reasoning behind that reversal @AndrewBarber ....